# BatchNode with cocos2d-x (javascript)

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I'm trying to create Browser game with cocos2d-x(javascript).

I have a problem with BatchNode.
on desktop computer, it works very well.(numbers of draw call: 3000→8)
But on android and iOS, it doesnt work.(3000→3000)
Both of them,desktop computer and smartphone, can show nodes and its Texture.

On android and iOS,BatchNode cannot work well?

Answer (score 0):

BatchNode doesn't work in Canvas mode, it only works on OpenGl/OpenGLES/WebGL

Link to GitHub issue: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-js/issues/1442